# Get url variable in a request validation file

Tags: laravel

I am using the url with an id variable to update a record:

```
Route::patch('ProjectsRevenueUpdateAjax/{id}'...
```

And I have my controller for this:

```
public function updateRevenue(ProjectRevenueUpdateRequest $request,$id)
    {
        // When using stdClass(), we need to prepend with \ so that Laravel won't get confused...
        $result = new \stdClass();
        $inputs = $request->all();
        $projectRevenueToUpdate = ProjectRevenue::find($id);
        $projectRevenueToUpdate->update($inputs);
        $result->result = 'success';
        $result->msg = 'Record updated successfully';

        return json_encode($result);
    }
```

So I'm calling the validation through another file which is ProjectRevenueUpdateRequest:

```
public function rules()
{
    $id = $this->id;
    $revenue = ProjectRevenue::find($id);
    $project_id = $revenue->project_id;
    $year = $this->year;
    $product_code = $this->product_code;
    return [
        'project_id' => 'required|unique:project_revenues,project_id,'.$id.',id,year,'.$year.',product_code,'.$product_code,
        'year' => 'required|unique:project_revenues,year,'.$id.',id,project_id,'.$project_id.',product_code,'.$product_code,
        'product_code' => 'required|unique:project_revenues,product_code,'.$id.',id,year,'.$year.',project_id,'.$project_id,
        'jan' => 'required',
        'feb' => 'required',
        'mar' => 'required',
        'apr' => 'required',
        'may' => 'required',
        'jun' => 'required',
        'jul' => 'required',
        'aug' => 'required',
        'sep' => 'required',
        'oct' => 'required',
        'nov' => 'required',
        'dec' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

My problem is that it cannot get the $id = $this->id from the url in my request validation file. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you try `$this->route('id');` in the form request

Comment: I just tried and did a dd($id); but I get undefined :(

Comment: Your route parameter is optional, are you actually providing a id in your request?

Comment: yes, I changed it to strict without the ?

Comment: Ok, I found out, it was my jquery that was not building the url correctly :(

Now your answer:
$id = $this->route('id'); works.

Thanks so much...